# some attributes from material design missing in bottom sheets

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-appcompat

So i want to add Bottom Sheets in my app and looked into the material design steps for doing so but the problem is I am unable to add attributes like app:behavior_hideable , app:behavior_peekHeight, etc .
I have looked in others code as well but didn't found anything solution to it.

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-beta05'

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'

I have included the latest dependencies available to me at this time.
Still there isn't any positive breakthrough.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think that somehow android studio was not auto-detecting those attributes .

So, by just sheer luck i tried to copy paste those attributes from Material design site (https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-sheet-behavior/) and that seems to work just fine.

Hope this works for you as well.